# Need A React Router Pro to help me

Tags: javascript, api, reactjs, routes, react-router

So today I played around with the react router and tried to modify [this example](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/examples/sidebar).

I want to achieve this:

- The side nav only displays the names
- when the user clicks on the name, the page displays the name, and ALL the items.

Example:

Click on drinks, the page would look like this

---

Drinks

Lemonade

3

Root beer

4

Iron Port

5

---

### My problems

*app.js*

```
const Item = ({ params: { category, item } }) => {
 const menuItem = data.lookupItem(category, item)

  return (
  <div>
   <h1>{menuItem.name}</h1>
   <p>${menuItem.price}</p>
  </div>
  )
}
```

I am having trouble understanding what the **params: { category, item }** is and where it comes from.

If you can do a gist of the solution, it takes less than 10 minutes if you know what do are doing, would be extremely helpful and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`params: { category, item }` comes from the `Router`. As the below code snippet, When you use Router, the component would get the `params` prop from the `Router`. The value of `params` comes from the route path. The `Item` matches the path `/category/:category/:item`, so the value of `{ category, item }`  comes from the corresponding location(`:item` and `:category`) of the route path.

```
<Router history={withExampleBasename(browserHistory, __dirname)}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="category/:category" components={{ content: Category, sidebar: CategorySidebar }}>
        <Route path=":item" component={Item} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
</Router>
```

Comment: holy smokes that was a great explanation. Would you mind modifying the code to get the page how I described?

Comment: @Regex102 I am sorry. I think it is better for you to achieve it by yourself.  It would be not very difficult after you have read the guide of react-router.